# How to remove the special character in SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a file `FileName.sql`, in that file when I try to deploy to server using PowerShell script (that's our company deployment tool), it always complains that there is a special character inside the file, hence deployment fails.

But it never says on which line the special character is, could you please help me, how to identify the special character in SQL file?

When I execute this `FileName.sql` file manually in SQL Server Management Studio, it will execute without error, but through PowerShell script, I am not able to deploy, so please help me.

How to identify the special character inside my SQL file?

```
select * from TableName
```

Comment: I can help you with this, but need more information. What do you mean exactly when you say you ‘deploy’ this file to a server using Powershell?

Comment: yes that's correct using Powershell script I am deploying the sql script to server, that's our normal process, all other sql files are fine, but one of the file is getting failed. this is the error message in pwoershal script : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException: Incorrect syntax near '�'.

Comment: Ok. I am still not sure what you mean...but it appears there is a syntax error in your SQL statement.

Comment: No syntax error, as I said I am able to excute the sql file script in sql server management studio, issue is only when I try to deploy using powershall script

Comment: so I need to know how to identify the special chacater in sql script file, is there any mechanisim or any tools

Comment: Remove code from the file until the error is gone. Then you now the errors has to be caused by the part you just removed. Narrow that down until you have only one statement left. Then look deeper into it and correct the error. Should the problem persist repeat.

Comment: The exception from Powershell which you posted above clearly states a syntax error. Your statement may work in SSMS, that doesn’t mean it is constructed properly in your PS script. Can you post some actual code?

Comment: I am sorry its Bank code, so I can't place over here

Comment: Ok. Well you will find it. Keep looking.

Comment: Was anything copy/pasted from the internet and put in your SQL statement?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue with the file itself. Just copy the code into a new file / change the encoding of the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([ColumnName])), CHAR(1), ''), CHAR(9), '')) [NewColumnName]
FROM TableName
```

I have used the `REPLACE()` function to remove the special characters:
`LTRIM()` & `RTRIM()` - Tab character or the Space bar character
`CHAR(1)` & `CHAR(9)` - ASCII Control Characters

If you are going to use this on multiple columns. You can create a function.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with `notepad++`.  Find the char and save/encode as ascii/utf8. Possibly someone edited the file in Word and you have special/fancy quotes or hyphen.

No clue if this helps, but this may.

Find-FancyCharacters.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string[]] 
    $Files
)

$badCharacters = @"
‘
’
–
"@

$badCharactersList = $badCharacters -split "`r`n"

if (-not $Files)
{
    $Files = @('D:\test\badchars.txt')
}

foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Checking file: $file..."
    $contents = Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8
    $lineNumber = 1
    foreach ($line in $contents)
    {
        foreach ($invalidChar in $badCharactersList)
        {
            if ($line -match $invalidChar)
            {
                Write-Output "Invalid Character found: f=$file, l=$lineNumber, c=$invalidChar"
                break
            }
        }

        $lineNumber++
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gill for your response, is this pwershall script ?